# Scaling of coordinates between different screen resolutions

Tags: delphi, coordinates, scaling, screen-resolution

I have projects developed in Delphi 10 on a laptop with a screen resolution of 96. I am now using Delphi 10.4 Community Edition on a Microsoft Surface with a screen resolution of 201. Is there a function or a settings that automatically converts numerically defined coordinates when scaling an application? To show what I mean I add this code snippet.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Canvas do
  begin
    MoveTo(0,0);
    LineTo(400,250);
    MoveTo(0,0);
    LineTo(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
  end;
end;
```

The first line drawn does not scale, the second one obviously does.

May I add:

If I compile the same code on my old laptop with a screen resolution of 96 and then run the exe file on my Surface Laptop with a screen resolution of 201 it scales ok, I was hoping there was a facility somewhere to compile my old programmes on my new computer without having to manually change all the code referring to coordinates x and y.

Comment: Since you are using different Delphi versions on different computers it is possible that your application executable is being built with different manifest file included in the exe itself. And since this manifest file tells operating system which scaling type your application is using such difference in manifest file might be cause of your problems.

Comment: @SilverWarior Your suggestion worked. See my own answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in scaling of coordinates in a TCanvas. You can use this CLASS HELPER:

```
TYPE
  TFormHelper = CLASS HELPER FOR TForm
                  FUNCTION Scale(Value : INTEGER) : INTEGER;
                END;

FUNCTION TFormHelper.Scale(Value : INTEGER) : INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    Result:=MulDiv(Value,CurrentPPI,Screen.DefaultPixelsPerInch)
  END;
```

Use it as in:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Canvas do
  begin
    MoveTo(Scale(0),Scale(0)); // Not needed, as 0 scaled is always 0, but... //
    LineTo(Scale(400),Scale(250));
    MoveTo(0,0);
    LineTo(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There is no need for a helper class. TControl, respectively TForm already has ScaleValue method for that purpose.

Comment: @dwrbudr: Didn't know of that function - probably implemented after I made my original helper. Also, it's not exactly the same. ScaleValue is a running calculation in a floating point variable (Single precision) which accumulates inaccuracies. My Scale function is a direct re-calculation of the value from (assumed) original 96dpi to current dpi without any intervening accumulative round-off problems.

Comment: @dwrbudr please look at my additional comment to my question, it might solicit some more thoughts.

Comment: @SilverWarior Thank you, I think you put me on the right track. I will have to learn about the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

To run my projects developed with Delphi 10 on my new computer with a higher screen resolution, using Delphi 10.4 Community Edition I change the setting
Project Options -> Application -> Manifest -> DPI Awareness to GDI Scaling and it all works like a charm.